# При вводе в инпут символа дать класс

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе первого символа в инпут сразу же давался класс, а не так как сейчас ? Проблемы с js/jquery, только учусь.

```js
var input = $('#inp_1');

input.on('change', function() {
  var inp = $('#inp_1').val();
  if (inp) {
      $('span').addClass('active');
  } else {
   $('span').removeClass('active');
  }
 });
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp_1" type="text">
<span class="descr_for_input_1">Вы ввели значение</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо события `change` используй `keyup`

Comment: Спасибо :) Не подскажите, где такие простенькие задачки с решениями можно поискать, чтоб набить руку? И аналог keyup на JS есть ?

Comment: Вообще советую вот этот ресурс: https://learn.javascript.ru/ , там оч много интересного по JS, а вот про события на JS тут же: https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: @YourDeveloper если ответ помог, не забудь, пожалуйста, отметить, что ответ правильный.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = $('#inp_1');

input.on('input', function() {
  var inp = $('#inp_1').val();
  if (inp) {
      $('span').addClass('active');
  } else {
   $('span').removeClass('active');
  }
 });
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp_1" type="text">
<span class="descr_for_input_1">Вы ввели значение</span>
```

Comment: А в чем разница между 'input' и 'keyup' ?